# Minimum vertex cover of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex, cover

If you have a binary tree that has 2^n - 1 vertices, where n >= 1, what is amount of vertices needed to have a minimum vertex cover?

Comment: It is better to first think about it yourself and share your ideas and thoughts.

Comment: There's always a minimum vertex cover of a tree that has no two adjacent vertices. A minimum vertex cover of a tree either includes the root or it doesn't. Applying these two rules gives you a way to compute the size of the minimum vertex cover of any tree.

Comment: @Haani Al-Ghalabi , Did I answer your question? If so please accept if not please put a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we have L levels (1 to L) where (n = 2^L - 1). The solution is to first pick all the nodes at level L - 1, then all nodes at L - 3, and so on. However, we stop depending on whether n is odd or even. If n is odd we stop at level 1 and if it is even we stop at level 2. This can be proved by strong induction (how ?).